# Flutter RiveAnimation.asset doesn't update after a setState()

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, flutter-animation, rive

Flutter RiveAnimation.asset doesn't update after a setState()

After switching from 'light' mode to 'dark' mode the setState() in the main file is called and certain widgets are built again.
One of these widgets contains these lines of code:

```
RiveAnimation.asset(
 Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light
   ? 'assets/RiveAssets/button.riv'
   : 'assets/RiveAssets/button_dark.riv',
 controllers: [_btnAnimationController],
),
```

The 'image' doesn't change at runtime, even though with the debugger I can see that these lines of code are reached each time the brightness is changed (because of the switch between the two modalities)

I tried by switching between two Icon instead of two RiveAnimation, and it works, with the same 'if' statement, in the same file, in the same widget.

Since it has been asked, I also paste here the 'State' widget inside the main file (it is a basic app where it's possible to switch between light and dark mode)

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Brightness brightness = Brightness.dark;

  void toggleBackgroundColor() {
    setState(() {
      brightness = brightness == Brightness.dark ? Brightness.light : Brightness.dark;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: brightness,
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          color: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: CustomAppBar(onColorToggle: toggleBackgroundColor),
        body: OnbodingScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The widget where 'RiveAnimation.asset' is present is inside the OnbodingScreen() widget.
But I would like to underline that if I replace 'RiveAnimation.asset' with the 'Image' widget, it is working! So I'm pretty sure there is something that I'm missing about the 'Rive' package.

Comment: Could you please add setstate code ?

Comment: Check out this answer also https://stackoverflow.com/a/67990696/13078639

Comment: Hi, thank you for trying to help me! I updated the post, hope that now it's more clear to you. Also, I checked the link you suggested but unfortunately, I think it's related to a different issue because would like to underline that if I replace 'RiveAnimation.asset' with the 'Image' widget, it is working! So I'm pretty sure there is something that  I'm missing about the 'Rive' package.